# jQuery autocomplete pop up on click

Tags: jquery

I would like to use this jQuery autocomplete plugin but I would like to make all the tags pop up when I click on the input box. is there any way that I can make it show all the tags on click instead of waiting to type and see the matches.

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( ".tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
<input  class="tags" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the `focus` with autocomplete.

```
$(".tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0
    }).bind('focus', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    });
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKMyU/).

Comment: @user2510039 I'm glad I was able to help.